# Selenium: horizontal scroll using Actions class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar, action, mcustomscrollbar

I have tried various to access this custom scroll bar on my web page through Selenium actions as well as Javascript Executor. The scroll bar scrolls through only 500 pixels when in fact I want it to scroll throughout the complete width. Any help is appreciated. Below is my current code snippet:

```
 WebElement slider = element("slider_div");
 WebElement scrollbar = element("scrollbar");
 int w = slider.getSize().getWidth();
 Actions move = new Actions(driver);
 move.dragAndDropBy(e, offset, 0).build() .perform();
```

I have also tried with the below solution, but still it did not work out:

```
WebElement slider = element("slider_div");
WebElement scrollbar = element("scrollbar");
int w = slider.getSize().getWidth();
clickByJavascript(slider);
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.sendKeys(Keys.RIGHT).build().perform();`
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What is `WebElement slider = element("slider_div");` and `WebElement scrollbar = element("scrollbar");` refering to exactly?

Comment: Hi Debanjan, 'slider' refers to the scrolling div and 'scrollbar' refers to the scrollbar element. Let me paste the HTML below:       
 
<div class="lcs_customScroller column-8" data-scroll-control=".columnScroller">  <-----scrollbar

<div class="lca_customScrollerOverflow" data-scroll-width=".columnScrollAuto" style="width: 16016px;"><------slider
</div>
</div>

Comment: Can you provide more information related to Html page, you question is related to `slide element or scroll page|element`

Comment: My question is related to a scroll page|element . Its a custom scrollbar within a div

Comment: Can you share any sample page to try for element horizontal scroll. Is this your question right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your scenarion over the site specified below, with horizontal and vertical scrolls.

Test URL « **`https://trello.com/b/LakLkQBW/jsfiddle-roadmap`**;

> Element Inner Vertical Scroll «

- Selenium java:

  ```java
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='board']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]") );
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop += 200;", element);
  }
  ```
- javascript `|` jquery:

  ```javascript
  var objDiv = $x("//div[@id='board']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")[0];
  console.log( objDiv );

  objDiv.scrollTop += 100; 
  //objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
  ```

> Element Inner Horizontal Scroll «

- Java Actions Class

  ```java
  WebElement horizontalbar = driver.findElement(By.id("board") );
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);

  Actions moveToElement = action.moveToElement( horizontalbar );
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      moveToElement.sendKeys(Keys.RIGHT).build().perform();
  }
  ```

> Scroll till the Element comes into view.

- javascript

  ```java
  public void scroll_Till_Element(String id) {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id( id ) );
      jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
  }
  ```

> Scroll till end of the page.

```java
public void scrollPage() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/q/33094727/5081877");

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body") );
    Actions scrollDown = actions.moveToElement( element );
    scrollDown.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).build().perform();
    //jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");

    Thread.sleep( 1000 * 4 );

    /*Actions scrollUP = actions.moveToElement( element );
    scrollUP.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.HOME).build().perform();*/
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, -document.body.scrollHeight)");

    scroll_Till_Element( "answer-33142037" );
}
```

for javascript you can use any of these.

```javascript
window.scrollBy(0,800);
window.scrollTo(0, -document.body.scrollHeight);
scroll(0, -document.body.scrollHeight);
```

@see

- [Page scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094727/selenium-scroll-till-end-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use below Lines to scroll from left to right

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(500000, 0)");
```

To scroll right to left use below lines:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(-500000, 0)");
```

This will scroll completely to the left or right as (50000) is a very big value to cover a page