# JavaScriptExecutor scroll into View is not working in my TestNG Automation

Tags: java, selenium, scroll, testng, javascriptexecutor

I am using the below code-

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Select Selection Field 3']"));
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
```

And it doesn't perform any function. I dont get any error but scrolling is becoming a blocker for me.
Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to [**scrollIntoView()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537189/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the  [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) as follows:

```
WebElement ele = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Select Selection Field 3']")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
```

In a single line:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Select Selection Field 3']"))));
```