# executeScript() method returns me null instead of scrolling horizontally towards right

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

The code is:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='table-wrapper']"));
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft=arguments[0].scrollWidth", element);
```

While debugging at third step, `executeScript` returned me "null".

Xpath is correct and locating well. I can't able to find locator of scroll so I am using whole locator of that particular div.  i.e `//div[@class='table-wrapper']`.

Comment: I'm sure that method is supposed to return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *`scrollLeft`* you can always [**Element.scrollIntoView()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689339/7429447) as follows:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='table-wrapper']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [scrollIntoView() not working for horizontal scroll (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537189/7429447)