# Selenium button click does not wait until JavascriptExecutor scroll down finishes. That leads to ElementClickIntercepted error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on button which is not viewable on to the screen so that first I have to scroll the window and then perform click operation, but before scrolling entirely happens using `JavascriptExecutor`, Selenium tries to click on button which leads to `ElementClickInterceptedException`.

```
WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".totalRow button"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", submitButton);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submitButton));
submitButton.click();
```

If I use `Thread.sleep(5000)` after scrolling this issue does not happen, but I do not want to use that. I tried using `JavascriptExecutor` and `Action` class that did not work either.

Comment: Please post the full error message when `ElementClickInterceptedException` is thrown. That will tell us which element is intercepting the click.

Comment: _`ElementClickInterceptedException`_: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: if you don't HAVE to use selenium, I would recommand that you try playwright. Both are great, but I've had better results in general with it. just in case

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any major issue in your code as such. The complete error stacktrace would have helped us to understand exactly which element intercepts the click throwing *`ElementClickInterceptedException`*.

However, a minor improvement would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) before you attempt to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537189/7429447) as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".totalRow button"))));
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".totalRow button"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IS waiting for the element to be clickable but it is not aware that another element is blocking the click until that click is attempted. There are two solutions to this problem:

1. You can use a JS click to click `submitButton`.

   ```
   WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".totalRow button"));
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", submitButton);
   w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submitButton));
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", submitButton);
   ```

   If you are creating UI test scripts, don't use this. Using a JS click will allow the script to click elements that a normal user will not be able to click. If you are just doing webscraping, etc. where you aren't trying to simulate actual user behavior, this method is fine.
2. Wait for the blocking element to be invisible. You'll know which element is blocking the click because the HTML of that element will be in the exception message.

   ```
   WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".totalRow button"));
   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", submitButton);
   By blockingElementLocator = ...;
   w.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(blockingElementLocator));
   w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submitButton)).click();
   ```